# How to make streamline with xarray and cartopy continuous?

Tags: python, python-xarray, cartopy

I am now using xarray dataset to plot streamline with cartopy on global map. However, the streamline is not continuous when crossing dateline. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
Code (only streamplot part) and the output figure are shown below:

```
wnd = xr.merge([u[::2,::2],v[::2,::2]])
proj = ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude = 180)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1,
                     subplot_kw={'projection': proj},
                     figsize=(12,7))
wind_plt = wnd.plot.streamplot(ax=ax,
                               transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                               x='longitude', y='latitude',
                               u='u', v='v',
                               arrowsize=2,arrowstyle='->',
                               color="black",
                               )

ax.coastlines(color = 'dimgray')
ax.set_extent([0,360,-90,90],crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_xticks(np.arange(0, 361,90), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.set_yticks(np.arange(-90,91,45), crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())  
ax.set_xlabel(' ')
ax.set_ylabel(' ')
ax.set_title(' ')
ax.text(70, 30, '03-12', fontsize = 14, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())

ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
plt.axis('off')

plt.savefig('0312.png', bbox_inches = 'tight', pad_inches = 0)
plt.close()
```

[image]

Thank you and all comments are welcome!

Comment: I suspect that the flowlines dont even cover the area near the dateline.

Comment: Yes, you're right!

Answer (score 3):

I suspect that your flowlines (streamplot data: X,Y,U,V) are not created to the full extent required to fill the plot area. Or, they were not created properly.

Here is my demo code that shows complete stream plots from a good set of data for you to try.

Note that, my data for the streamplot is complete, therefore, there will be no gap around the dateline.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import numpy as np

noproj = projection=ccrs.PlateCarree()
myproj = projection=ccrs.PlateCarree(central_longitude=180)

# Creating dataset
w = 180
h = 90
# Domains of X,Y: (-180, 180), (-90, 90)
# Domains of X,Y are chosen to comply with ability to plot
#  successfully with Cartopy.
Y, X = np.mgrid[-h:h:100j, -w:w:100j]
U = -1 - X**2 + Y
V = 1 + X - Y**2
#speed = np.sqrt(U**2 + V**2)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=[5,6.7])

# Plot on ordinary projection
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211, projection = noproj)
ax1.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=[0.4, 0.8], transform=noproj)
ax1.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=noproj)
ax1.coastlines(resolution='110m', alpha=0.3)
ax1.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
ax1.set_title("Zero-meridian-centered")

# Plot on projection with shifted center
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212, projection = myproj)
ax2.streamplot(X, Y, U, V, density=[0.4, 0.8], transform=noproj)
ax2.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, 90], crs=noproj)
ax2.coastlines(resolution='110m', alpha=0.3)
ax2.gridlines(draw_labels=True)
ax2.set_title("Dateline-centered")
plt.show()
```

[image: 2plots]